# How to change python tkinter progressbar height?

Tags: python, tkinter, loading

Please help me, I want to make a loading bar in tkinter but its height is too small!

I tried to find something but I know that tkinter Progressbar doesn't have the height option. Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Have you tried anything or have you wrote any code?

Answer (score 1):

You can contain the progress bar inside a `Frame`, filling it, then set the dimensions of that `Frame` to whatever you like. The trick is to turn off "propagation" so the `Frame` only fills up to the `width` and `height` you specify.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
# create a frame to contain your progress bar
frame = ttk.Frame(root, width=120, height=90)  # set your desired dimensions here
frame.pack(expand=True, fill='none')
frame.pack_propagate(False)  # allows you to explicitly set the dimensions of the frame

progbar = ttk.Progressbar(frame, mode='indeterminate')  # example progress bar!
progbar.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root.mainloop()  # run the app
```

Note that you can also do this with the `grid` geometry manager; you'd just use `frame.grid_propagate(False)` instead!

Comment: I think using `progbar.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)` (there should be no `self` because it is not inside a class function) is better than using `pack()` and `pack_propagate(False)` together. Also using `if __name__ == '__main__'` is useless for your example.

Comment: @acw1668 Ack! I've removed `self` - force of habit hahaha. Also removed `if __name__`